# Limit Comparison Test Question

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find the end behavior of
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$
using the limit comparison test, but I'm having a hardtime finding the comparing equation. I would appreciate if someone could either give me advice to finding the comparing equations and/or the equation of the this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the limit comparison test, you usually compare to something simpler. You get something simpler if you drop lower order terms. Try that approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$n^2+1 \le 2 n^2$, so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 n^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is applicable could you explain?

Comment: Just use the comparison test directly. The harmonic series $\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent, and your series is, term by term, greater than the harmonic series, hence it diverges too.

Answer (score 5):

The one that came first to my mind was:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ $>$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n+1}}$ $=$

$=$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n+1}}$ $=$ $\infty$ $\hspace{99mm} \blacksquare$

Answer (score 4):

HINT: $\sqrt{n^2+1}$ is approximately $n$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}}}{\frac1n}=1.$$